# Regex to find IP Address in specific places

Tags: regex, go

I have a yaml file which has IP Address as value with IP Address as key string. Some times the the value maybe have multiple IP's on new line each. There are some other key:value pairs in this file whose value also has format like IP Address(x.x.x.x) but as the key is not IP Address, I don't want to consider this to matched with IP Address regex. Below is the sample yaml file in which I only want to find/match regex for IP Address only with key having IP Address and its values spanning over multi line.

```
test-key-1: some_value
test-key-2: 8.23.12.0
test-key-3: some_value
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
 127.0.0.1
 127.0.0.1
 127.0.0.1
test-key-4: test-value
```

As seen in above sample yaml file, test-key-2 has value which matches IP Address like format. But I only want to match the IP Address and replace it with some test value. So the expected output should be as below where all IP Addresses are replaced with "some-replaced-value" but the test-key-2 is not changed even though its value matches IP Address like format. While replacing the multi line IP Addresses with replacement text, the space at start of each line have to be retained as it is to have valid yaml format for multiline values.

```
test-key-1: some_value
test-key-2: 8.23.12.0
test-key-3: some_value
IP Address: some-replaced-value
 some-replaced-value
 some-replaced-value
 some-replaced-value
test-key-4: test-value
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have some values which are valid IP addresses, to me, it seems like you need a YAML parser as a first round to first extract the keys-value pairs you're interested in (or exclude fields you are not) and then operate only on the results

I am not a golang user, but this seems quite relevant [Golang Map YAML Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270780/golang-map-yaml-objects)

I suspect your program would then take a form like

```
read yaml file

for each key-value pair
  if the key name is "IP Address"
    split the string
      replace each matching member (also error for non-matching?)
```

When transforming, it also may be better to use a dedicated IP parser as it probably provided by `net` than a regex, which may have extra features (such as trivially providing if the address is local or handling IPv6)